# Random effects for second order in R mixed models

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mixed-model

I am fitting a mixed effects model in R using nlme

```
lme(y~x+I(x^2),random=~x|subject,data=train)
```

Is this the correct way or should it be

```
lme(y~x+I(x^2),random=~x+I(x^2)|subject,data=train)
```

What is the difference in the interpretation of fitting these two models

Comment: I recommend that you study some relevant literature to understand what these random effects mean. Pinheiro, J.C., and Bates, D.M. (2000) "Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS" is a bit technical, but still a recommended read. More friendly for beginners is Zuur, Ieno, Walker, Saveliev and Smith (2009) "Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R".

Comment: @Roland, my question is not about random effects in general . It is adressing the quardatic random effects. What is the intuitive interpretation of making your second order also random

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Correct" is somewhat context-dependent (both models *could* be sensible under the appropriate circumstances), but in general I would say that the second - including both the linear and the quadratic term in the random effects - makes more sense as a default. The default can reasonably be stated as "put all terms in the random effect that can XXX be estimated from the experimental design"; depending on whom you listen to in the current [Barr et al.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749596X12001180) vs. [Bates et al.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04967) controversy, XXX should be replaced either with "in principle" (Barr et al.) or  "practically" (Bates et al.).

If you leave out the quadratic term, you are essentially asserting that the constant and linear terms vary across subjects, but the quadratic term doesn't.  I don't see any very sensible justification for this assumption (again, there *might* be one for your system): the statistical model is

$$
\begin{split}
y_i & \sim \textrm{Normal}(\mu_i,\sigma^2) \\
\mu_i & = (\beta_0 + b_{0,g_i}) + (\beta_1 + b_{1,g_i}) x + (\beta_2 +b_{2,g_i}) x^2 \\
b_{.,g_i} & \sim \textrm{MVN}(0,\Sigma)
\end{split}
$$
where $\Sigma$ is the variance-covariance matrix of the random effects and $g_i$ is the index of the group to which observation $i$ belongs.  If you omit the `I(x^2)` term in the random effect, you're zeroing out $b_{2,g_i}$.